# al intentar recibir y enviar por medio de uart en un atmega2560 me aparecen caracteres basura

Tags: c, arduino, gcc

estoy intentando enviar y recibir "datos" a un atmega2560 por medio de uart,pero al hacer esto me retorna solo la primera parte bien sea de la palabra o el numero y despues imprime caracter basura;pero cuando el micro-controlador  se encuentra en la funcion Tx si envia de manera correcta los datos

de manera siguiente esta el codigo de lo que corresponderia a Rx

```
char uart_Rx(void) {
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1<< RXC0))); /* Wait until data exists. */
   

    return (UDR0);
   
}

void printstring(char *mystring){
    unsigned char i=0;
    while (mystring[i]){
        uart_Tx(mystring[i]);
        i++;
    }
}

void get_Rx(char *buf){
unsigned char x;
unsigned int c=0;
x=uart_Rx();
buf[c]=x;
c++;

}
int main(void) {
    uint8_t bufSize = 125;
    char* buf;
    DDRB = 0xff;
    PORTB = 0<<7;
    char SerialData=0;
    uart_Init();
    //o_i();
    while(1) {
            
            get_Rx(buf);
            printstring(buf);
            printstring("\n");
        
        }
    }
```

[image: Datos antes a ingresar]

[image: Salida de los datos ingresados]

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar `Serial.print` y `Serial.read`?

Comment: por lo que no estoy trabajando directamente en el ide de arduino sino con avr-gcc y un edior de texto y  quiero entender a fondo como funciona el micro-controlador

Comment: Felicitaciones por tu empeño. Aunque no logres nada, aprenderás mucho.

Answer (score 0):

la solucion para este tipo de problema es configuar el bit (0<<UCSZn2) del registro lo cual corresponderia a dar un configuracion de 8-bits para Character Size